# How to run Main() method from C# program in the thread pool?

Tags: c#, f#, threadpool, program-entry-point

I wonder, how can I run the method `Main()` of C# program in the thread pool like I do it in F#:

```ml
let main() =
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World!")

do Task.Factory.StartNew(main).Wait()
```

What is the alternative code in C# programming language? Because in the simple console application, there is only the way to use:

```
static void Main() // or with int as the return type and args[]
                   // in method arguments but it's not important for this question
```

And I can't somewhere also add smth like in F#:

```ml
do Task.Factory.StartNew(main).Wait()
```

Or I just don't know the all possibilites of C# program execution?

Comment: Your F# `main` is not actually the same - the F# actually creates an implicit function that calls the `do`.  The equivalent would be to annotate the F# bit with `[<Entrypoint>]`

Comment: @JohnPalmer yeap, you're correct

Comment: I think that it might be a good idea to scrap the idea of calling Main altogether, use other functions if you want to invoke them recursively. I've always seen calling Main as bad style.

Comment: This is completely pointless. You're just spawning another thread while the original thread executing Main is just waiting. You do not gain anything with this, especially not concurrency or performance. You lose.

Comment: @usr - this obviously is not the real (end) code.

Comment: @HenkHolterman whatever the code is, starting a task and waiting on it directly isn't useful. I feel this question is too far removed from reality to be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could I suggest that you refrain from that. I'm fairly certain that you should write other functions which you can then add to the thread pool as required.

In most programming languages, it's bad style to call the main function; write other functions to do your work if that's how you want to do it. 
Basically:

```
static void Function(){
    //Do stuff
}
static void Main(){
  TaskFactory.StartNew(Function).wait();
}
```